# how to make a sample of the generated xml?

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x, lxml, xml.etree

I create xml structure using the methods lxml.etree.Element

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

parent = lxml.etree.Element('root')
child = lxml.etree.Element('sub')
child.text = 'text'
parent.append(child)
```

I need to do the following query:

```
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(parent)
text = doc.xpath('sub/text()')
print(text)
```

but I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\6_first_store_names_cat_full_xml_nested\q.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(parent)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\lxml\html__init__.py", line 600, in
>   document_fromstring
>       value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)   File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3003, in lxml.etree.fromstring
>   (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:67277)   File "parser.pxi", line 1784, in
>   lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:101615)
>   ValueError: can only parse strings
>
> > > >

help my please

Answer (score 0):

`lxml.html.document_fromstring()` accepts a string, not an `Element` as you are passing in. Try passing in `lxml.etree.tostring(parent)`:

```
s = lxml.etree.tostring(parent)
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(s)
```

Comment: for python3 doc = lxml.etree.tounicode(parent) not worked(
error message:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\6_first_store_names_cat_full_xml_nested\q.py", line 11, in <module>
    text = doc.xpath('sub/text()')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: Leave the assignment to doc as is, just change the parameter. I'll make changes above to make this more obvious.